# How can I capture shell variable output to use in my capistrano task

Tags: environment-variables, ruby, rails

I am using capistrano to deploy a Ruby on Rails application. I previously was using Centos. In converting my task to be used with Ubuntu, I have a task that I was using for Centos was:

```
 capture("env | grep ENV_VAR").split("=").last
```

This would capture the output of that variable on the remote system to be used in my code. However this code doesn't seem to work with Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me how I can capture the output of a variable using capistrano and ubuntu?

I have tried

```
capture("echo $ENV_VAR")
```

But that prints out an empty string. I am assuming the issue is reated to "$" but I am not sure.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Use [`printenv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/printenv.1.html) instead**, which does not require a shell:

```ruby
capture('printenv ENV_VAR')
```

Replace *`ENV_VAR`* with the name of the environment variable you want. Do not prepend `$`.

Although `printenv` is [not POSIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246420/11938), [GNU/Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) systems like Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, and CentOS support it because [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) provides it, and it works on [many other *nix systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284069/11938), like FreeBSD. The reason you need to use `printenv` instead of `env` is that `printenv ENV_VAR` outputs the value of *`ENV_VAR`*, while `env ENV_VAR` tries to run a command called *`ENV_VAR`*, which is not what you want.

---

*The rest of this post covers other methods, their limitations, and how they can be improved. This is optional reading, since `printenv` is simple and solves the problem fully.*

**Your original method**, `capture("env | grep ENV_VAR").split("=").last`, should not be used even on a system where it *does* appear to work, because it is unreliable. It `grep`s for the variable name everywhere in the `VAR=val` line, and thus will return results for variables whose names--or even values--*contain* the name of the desired variable. Using `^ENV_VAR=` instead of *`ENV_VAR`* fixes this problem by matching the name only when it appears at the [beginning of the line](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) (`^`) and requiring a `=` character to appear right after it. However, it is possible for the *value* of an environment variable to contain an `=` character, and since you call `split` and `last`, you are actually getting the longest trailing substring of the value that contains no `=`. Even if you fixed that, the method is still needlessly complex when all you need is `printenv`.

[**The solution you found**](https://askubuntu.com/a/615497/22949), `capture("/bin/sh -c 'echo $ENV_VAR'")`, will work *most of the time*, but will return an incorrect value when the variable *(a)* contains whitespace other than single space characters surrounded by non-whitespace, or *(b)* contains [globbing characters](https://foldoc.org/glob) like `*`, `?`, and `[` if they happen to match any filenames. The problem is that, in the shell command `echo $ENV_VAR`, the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `$ENV_VAR` is not [quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Double-Quotes), so [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [globbing](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) are performed. `echo` reinserts whitespace but not always in the same way: `echo foo bar` prints `foo bar`, but so does `echo foo   bar`. This problem can be solved by placing `"` `"` quotes around the expansion, though you will have to either escape *them* so the Ruby interpreter doesn't take them as ending the `"`-quoted string and starting a new one, or you can `'`-quote the Ruby string and escape any internal `'` characters.

You also get a wrong result in the less common situation that the value of *`ENV_VAR`* begins with an option that `echo` supports. Different `echo` implementations support different options; `-n` and `-e` are common. Most shells have `echo` as a builtin and may support different options from other shells and from `/bin/echo`. This is to say that [`echo` is not very portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). It's reasonable for inspecting environment variables interactively, when you'll probably realize if something odd is happening, but less so for scripting. `echo`'s portability woes are exacerbated by how `/bin/sh` is not always `bash`. [In Ubuntu it is `dash`.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) This can be avoided by using `printf '%s\n'` or `printf "%s\n"` instead of `echo` (or, in your case, `printf %s` might suffice).

Thus your solution can be improved to `capture('/bin/sh -c \'printf "%s\n" "$ENV_VAR"\'')`. This may look wrong to experienced shell scripters who do not know Ruby; note that Ruby, unlike Bash and other Bourne-style shells, treats `\'` as a literal `'` inside a `'` `'`-quoted string. Even though it's correct, your colleagues will have to look at it twice to satisfy themselves of that, even if they are proficient in both Ruby and shell scripting. `capture('printenv ENV_VAR')` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I finally stumbled across this answer. The way to do this is to load the bash shell and pass  the command to it.

```
capture("/bin/sh -c 'echo $ENV_VAR'")
```